# ¿Por qué el .css no funciona en un formulario creado en Symfony y agregado en la plantilla Twig mediante render controller?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

He creado un formulario siguiendo las indicaciones de la [documentación de Symfony sobre formularios](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html).

Luego, siguiendo [lo explicado aquí](https://symfony.com/doc/7.0/templates.html#embedding-controllers) uso `render controller` para insertar ese formulario y su respectivo controlador dentro de un contenido HTML.

Todo funciona bien, excepto que el `.css` no aplica específicamente para lo que es el formulario. No es problema del `.css` porque el mismo aplica para todos los demás elementos, e incluso si copio todo el HTML generado y lo pongo junto con el `.css` funciona (como podrán ver con un snippet  al final). Pero al probarlo en el navegador no funciona. No sé si hay que hacer algo en particular para que el `.css` aplique.

Si pongo el `form` directamente sí aplica, pero necesito también el controlador, y por eso lo estoy poniendo con `render ...controller`.

El HTML está en un archivo llamado `footer.html` con este contenido:

```
{% apply inline_css %}
    <footer id="footer"> 
      <div class="footer-newsletter"> 
        <div class="container"> 
          <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-lg-6"> 
              <h4>Our Newsletter</h4> <p>Tamen quem nulla quae legam multos aute sint culpa legam noster magna</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-6">  {{ render(controller(
                'App\\Controller\\SubscribeController::new'
            )) }}    
            </div>
            ... etc
{% endapply %}
```

Luego, este archivo es agregado a una plantilla Twig con `include`:

```
...

{% include 'footer.html' %}

...
```

Al probar la página en el navegador el botón aparece en gris y como un botón normal y el email aparece en negro. Dejo una captura de cómo se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y debería verse así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo aquí un snippet del HMTL y del `.css` que se generan. Como ven, aquí sí funciona, el botón `Suscribir` aparece con color naranja y el email aparece en rojo. El código del snippet, tanto el `HTML` como el `.css`, lo he tomado del código fuente de la página directamente, no entiendo por qué allí el `.css` no aplica para la parte del formulario.

```css
#footer {
  background: #404040;
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px
}

#footer .footer-newsletter {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: #404040
}

#footer .footer-newsletter h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 600
}

#footer .footer-newsletter form {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px
}

#footer .footer-newsletter form button#subscribe_Suscribir {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #e96b56;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 50px
}

#footer .footer-newsletter form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #e6573f
}

#footer .footer-top {
  background: #3b3b3b;
  border-top: 1px solid #474747;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #474747;
  padding: 60px 0 30px 0
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-info {
  margin-bottom: 30px
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-info h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 700
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-info p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: #fff
}

#footer .footer-top .social-links a {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #545454;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin-right: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  transition: 0.3s
}

#footer .footer-top .social-links a:hover {
  background: #e96b56;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none
}

#footer .footer-top h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 12px
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links {
  margin-bottom: 30px
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul i {
  padding-right: 2px;
  color: #ec7f6d;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul li:first-child {
  padding-top: 0
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul a {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-links ul a:hover {
  color: #e96b56
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-contact {
  margin-bottom: 30px
}

#footer .footer-top .footer-contact p {
  line-height: 26px
}

#footer .copyright {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px
}

#footer .credits {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff
}

label.required:before {
  content: "*";
}

#subscribe_email {
  color: red;
  border: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  width: calc(100% - 140px)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello PostController!</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,&lt;svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22&gt;&lt;text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22&gt;⚫️&lt;/text&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">

  <script src="/build/runtime.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/build/vendors-node_modules_symfony_stimulus-bridge_dist_index_js-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_js_boo-e61552.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/build/app.js" defer=""></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="example-wrapper">
    <h1>Hello Hello world!! ✅</h1>

    This friendly message is coming from: Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!
  </div>


  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="footer-newsletter">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h4>Our* Newsletter</h4>
            <p>Tamen quem nulla quae legam multos aute sint culpa legam noster magna</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <form name="subscribe" method="get" action="/subscription">
              <div class="my-custom-class-for-errors">

              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col" id="id-email">
                  <div>
                    <label for="subscribe_email" class="required">Email</label><input type="email" id="subscribe_email" name="subscribe[email]" required="required" value="ac@gmail.com">
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div><button type="submit" id="subscribe_Suscribir" name="subscribe[Suscribir]">Suscribir</button></div>
              <input type="hidden" id="subscribe__token" name="subscribe[_token]">
            </form>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
            <h4>Useful Links</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">About us</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Terms of service</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Privacy policy</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
            <h4>Our Services</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Web Design</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Web Development</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Product Management</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Marketing</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="bx bx-chevron-right"></i> <a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-contact">
            <h4>Contact Us</h4>
            <p> A Street <br> New York, NY 535000<br> United States <br><br> <strong>Phone:</strong> +1 55<br> <strong>Email:</strong> info@example.com<br> </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-info">
            <h3>About Me</h3>
            <p>Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat lide par naso tierra. Justo eget nada terra videa magna derita valies darta donna mare fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus.</p>
            <div class="social-links mt-3"> <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="bx bxl-twitter"></i></a> <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a> <a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a> <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="bx bxl-linkedin"></i></a>              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="copyright"> © Copyright <strong><span>Me</span></strong>. All Rights Reserved </div>
      <div class="credits"> Designed by <a href="#">Me</a> </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```